# Mysql ignores encoding "koi8u_general_ci"

Tags: mysql, sql

[It is 100% this encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CzBB.png)

[Problem while inserting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hexY0.png)

Somewhere saw that it can be problem with 'root' user, but I use other one. This encoding has to be for Ukrainian language (i have changed table encoding) but while inserting [Ukrainian text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHavx.png), it shows me a problem. I havent found what to do, pls help me. I use mysql.

Ah and my table is [it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYJs0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer:

I tried to change encoding this way: (doesnt work)

```
ALTER TABLE `questions` COLLATE koi8u_general_ci;
```

But I had to do it this way:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET koi8u COLLATE koi8u_general_ci;
```

so it works))